# Can associative array values be arrays

Tags: php

Here is a simple problem that I was unable to solve with php.I want to convert the first array to something like this: `["BMW"=>["g4","g3"], "Mercedes"=>["f1"]]`

```
$array = ["F1" => "Mercedes", "g3"=>"BMW", "g4"=>"BMW"];
$newArray = [];

foreach($array as $key=>$value){
  if(!in_array($value, $newArray){
      $element = $value => [$key];
      array_push($newArray, $element);
  } else {
      array_push($newArray[$value],$key);
  }
}
```

`$element = $value =>[];` on line 6 was my intuitive solution but is invalid.

Am I using a poor pattern, is this inadvisable? According to [official documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php), *"The value can be of any type."*

Comment: You can certainly have arrays as entries in  arrays, but `=>` can only be used in array initializes, so `$element = $value =>[];` is meaningless.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simply do -

```
$array = ["F1" => "Mercedes", "g3"=>"BMW", "g4"=>"BMW"];
$newArray = [];

foreach($array as $key => $value) {
    $newArray[$value][] = $key;
}

print_r($newArray);
```

**Output**

```
Array
(
    [Mercedes] => Array
        (
            [0] => F1
        )

    [BMW] => Array
        (
            [0] => g3
            [1] => g4
        )

)
```

For the order you are expecting add `ksort($newArray);`

The output will be -

```
Array
(
    [BMW] => Array
        (
            [0] => g3
            [1] => g4
        )

    [Mercedes] => Array
        (
            [0] => F1
        )

)
```

[ksort()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ksort.php)

[Demo](https://eval.in/815983)

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
<?php
$array = ["F1" => "Mercedes", "g3"=>"BMW", "g4"=>"BMW"];
$newArray = [];

foreach($array as $key=>$value){
$newArray[$value][]=$key;
}
echo "<pre>";
print_r($newArray);
exit;
?>
```